# EditText TextWatcher replace with LiveData

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-databinding, android-livedata

Is there a way to replace `EditText` `TextWatcher` with two way databinding pattern?

I tried:

```
class AddViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    val description = MutableLiveData<String>()
}
```

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/descriptionEditText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_spacing"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_input_background"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:minHeight="200dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="@{viewModel.description}"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/postButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

I found something similar [here](https://medium.com/@vegeta2102/two-way-data-binding-with-inputtextedittext-google-material-4957217229df), but somehow I can't make it work.

**UPDATE:**

I was only missing `=` sign after `@`

`android:text="@{viewModel.description}"` -> `android:text="@={viewModel.description}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use OnTextChanged property in your XML

```
 <data>

    <variable
        name="onTextChanged"
        type="androidx.databinding.adapters.TextViewBindingAdapter.OnTextChanged" />
 </data>
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/descriptionEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_spacing"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_input_background"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="200dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:onTextChanged="@{viewModel.description}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/postButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

Now you can pass onTextChanged to included layout like below.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        layout="@layout/base_edittext_view"
        app:onTextChanged="@{(text, start, before, count) -> viewModel.onTextChanged(text)}"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then you need to add this method in your ViewModel

```
fun description(s: CharSequence,start: Int,before : Int,count :Int){
    //TODO write your implementation here ...
   }
```

Comment: it gives `unknown attribute  android:onTextChanged` error

Comment: You need to add databinding adapter. Check this again

Comment: I am accepting your answer, but key element what I was missing was that I actually dont need a onChangeListener at all if I am using two way databinding. Key thing what I was missing is `=` sign after `@`, it should look like this `android:text="@={viewModel.description}"`